# m2crypto: undefined symbol: sslv3_method

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, m2crypto

I tried to install M2Crypto with:

pip install M2Crypto

But when I try to import M2Crypto I get an error:

```
>>> import M2Crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from M2Crypto import (ASN1, AuthCookie, BIO, BN, DH, DSA, EVP, Engine, Err,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/ASN1.py", line 15, in 
    from M2Crypto import BIO, m2, util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/BIO.py", line 10, in 
    from M2Crypto import m2, six, util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/m2.py", line 30, in 
    from M2Crypto.m2crypto import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/m2crypto.py", line 26, in 
    _m2crypto = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/m2crypto.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_m2crypto', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.so: undefined symbol: sslv3_method
```

Comment: What is the version of you python, OpenSSL, swig, and gcc? I hope all installed from the standard Ubuntu packages, aren't they? Please file a bug with ALL this information to https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

If you use ubuntu, you should use the m2crypto(python-m2crypto) from apt server, it was built with all necessary dependencies:

```
pip uninstall M2crypto # remove the current error version
apt install python-m2crypto -y # install new version from the repo
```